# How to add an image on top of AVPlayerView using CALayer in macOS app?

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to place an imagelayer on videolayer, using CALayer. 
For that, playerview is added to videolayer and it is added to parent layer. Next I am trying to add imagelayer to playerview by "contentoverlayview" property, but it is showing nil. How can I add imagelayer to videolayer?

```
    let videoURL = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")


    var player: AVPlayer? = nil
    if let videoURL = videoURL {
        player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    }
    let playerView = AVPlayerView(frame: self.view.frame)
    playerView.player = player


    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    videoLayer.frame = playerView.frame
    videoLayer.contents = playerView

    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = self.view.frame



    //playerView.player?.play()

    //Image
    let overlayImage = NSImageView(frame:NSRect(x: 10, y: 30,    width: 72, height: 72))
    let img = NSImage(contentsOfFile:"/Users/Documents/app/mages/image.png")

    overlayImage.image = img
    //playerView.addSubview(overlayImage)

    let imageLayer = CALayer()
    imageLayer.contents = img
    imageLayer.frame = NSRect(x: 50, y: 30, width: 72, height: 72)

    //        parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    //        parentLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
    //        let overlayVIew = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 10, y: 30, width: 100, height: 100))
    //        playerView.contentOverlayView = overlayVIew
    //        self.view.layer = parentLayer
    self.view.addSubview(playerView)
    print("layering \(playerView.contentOverlayView)")
    if let layer = playerView.contentOverlayView?.layer {
        print("layer is available")
        layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
    }
```

I wanted to know how to add image on video top using CALayers in macOS.